# Google sheets loop search for string and clear adjacent cells

Tags: javascript, loops, search, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a loop in Google sheets script that will search column A for text string: "x" and clear adjacent cells in column B-X and AC-AH.

Edit: Sorry forgot to say what I've done...

My Excel VBA macro is as follows:

```
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("a11:a50")

    For Each rng2 In rng1
        If rng2 = "x" Then rng2.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 23).ClearContents
    Next
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim rng4 As Range
    Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("a11:a50")

    For Each rng4 In rng3
        If rng4 = "x" Then rng4.Offset(0, 28).Resize(, 6).ClearContents
    Next
```

I found this script provided by Simon Staton ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462125/google-spreadsheets-script-to-delete-any-rows-where-a-string-is-found)), but it's to delete the whole row and I don't want to delete the row, just clear some contents within it:

```
/* Delete rows */
function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var toDelete = [];

  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    for(var column = 0;column<values[row].length;column++){
      if (values[row][column].indexOf("WordThatExistsInOneRow") > -1){
        toDelete.push(row);
      }
    }
  }

  for(var deleteRow = toDelete.length-1; deleteRow >= 0;deleteRow--){
    sheet.deleteRow(toDelete[deleteRow]+1);
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

RESULT: Here's what I ended with, thanks to Ed Nelson's answer below... I had to tweek it to start at row 11, not the very first row:

```
function copyfeb() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var a = sheet.getRange(11, 1, lr, lc).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
          if (a[i][0].indexOf("x")!= -1){
           var delete1=sheet.getRange(i+11, 1, 1, 24)
           var delete2=sheet.getRange(i+11, 29, 1, 6)
           delete1.clearContent()
           delete2.clearContent()
   }}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
  var lc=sheet.getLastColumn()
  var a = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr, lc).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
          if (a[i][0].indexOf("x")!= -1){
           var delete1=sheet.getRange(i+2, 2, 1, 23)
           var delete2=sheet.getRange(i+2, 29, 1, 6)
           delete1.clearContent()
           delete2.clearContent()
   }}}
```