# cascading row deletion javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, delete-row

I start in the programming and in the google sheet folder I would like to delete the lines after 60 days according to the date column L (12). the program works but as soon as a line is deleted, all the other lines are deleted.
find below my code on google app script.

```
//trouver le nom du classeur
  var date1 ; 
  var date2 = new Date();
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var couleur ;
  var feuilles = classeur.getSheets();
  // for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )

//trouver le nombre de feuilles dans le classeur ???


 
//pour chaque feuille, il faut
//pour chaque ligne, étudier la cellule L
//si vide ou < 31 alors rien
//si >= effacer la ligne 
  
function coloriage() {
  for (var i=0 ;i<feuilles.length ; i ++) {
    var feuille = feuilles[i] ;
    var transports = feuille.getDataRange();
    var donnees = transports.getValues();    
    for (var ligne = 6 ; ligne < donnees.length ; ligne++) {        
      date1 = donnees[ligne][11]; 
      if (date1 != "") {
        // différence de jours
        var jours = Math.round((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        //Logger.log("ligne= "+ligne+ " date1= "+date1+" jours= "+jours);
        if (jours < 40) {
          if (jours<20) { couleur = "#fff" ; }
          if ((jours>=20)&&(jours<30)) { couleur = "#fd0" ; }
          if ((jours>=30)&&(jours<40)) { couleur = "#f75" ; }
          feuille.getRange(ligne+1,1,1,12).setBackground(couleur);
          }
        else { 
        feuille.deleteRows(ligne+1,1)
        Logger.log("ligne "+(ligne+1)+" supprimée ; nb de jours "+jours);
        ligne --
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you have not defined `date2` in your function

Comment: it's define at the beginning `var date2 = new Date();`

Comment: don't hesitate to share a sample / n'hésite pas à partager un fichier simplifié

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Spreadsheets script to delete any rows where a string is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462125/google-spreadsheets-script-to-delete-any-rows-where-a-string-is-found)

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop with line, and inside the loop you affect the value of line `ligne --` ... weird. If you want to remove rows, reverse your loop as follows

```
for (var ligne = donnees.length-1 ; ligne >= 6 ; ligne--)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i'm going to work on that this week end

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply remove the `ligne --` instruction as whenever the code ends up on the `else` branch, it creates an infinite loop and all the rows end up being deleted.

Therefore, your `else` will look simply like this:

```
else { 
   feuille.deleteRows(ligne+1,1);
   Logger.log("ligne "+(ligne+1)+" supprimée ; nb de jours "+jours);
}
```