# How to select my specific columns in this code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ive already wrote this code thad parcially do what i want, but have one big problem, how do i use more than the first column, because this code exclusively use the column A, i want the option to specify which one or if i want, use all, can somebody help me ;)

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('LEADS FRESCOS'); // change to your own
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=values.length;i>0;i-=1){
     var lcVal=values[i-1][0].toLowerCase() //Change to all lower case
     var index = lcVal.indexOf("trabalho");
     if (lcVal.indexOf("trabalho") > -1){
     s.deleteRow(i)};
  }}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Spreadsheets script to delete any rows where a string is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462125/google-spreadsheets-script-to-delete-any-rows-where-a-string-is-found)

Comment: It looks like you included code from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, [edit] to make sure you do **ALL** the following: 1.Include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, 2. Mention the author's name, and 3. [Quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to delete rows by searching for a value from all columns.
- From your showing script, you want to run by the onEdit trigger and/or also want to run by the script editor.

In this case, how about the following modification patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your showing script is modified. Please modify your script as follows.

##### From:

```
var lcVal=values[i-1][0].toLowerCase()
```

##### To:

```
var lcVal = values[i - 1].join("").toLowerCase();
```

- By this pattern, all columns are used.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the values are overwritten by the new values. I thought that this method might be a lower process cost than the above modification.

##### Modified script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('LEADS FRESCOS');
  var range = s.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues().filter(r => !r.join("").includes("trabalho"));
  range.clearContent().offset(0, 0, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)